# SQL populate new column based on criteria from another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where a doctor can work in multiple locations -- one while the others are not. Each location is in a state. I want to create a column that shows the state of the primary location for that doctor. So if a location is not primary, then I want to see the state for the primary location.

I'm trying to create the `PrimaryLocationState` column but I can't seem to get this.

```
    declare @t table (doctorid int,
                      primarylocation char,
                      state varchar(2)
                      )

    insert into @t 
    values (1, 'Y', 'FL'), (1, 'N', 'GA'),
           (2, 'Y', 'TX'), (2, 'N', 'CA');
```

I'm trying to get this result:

```
    DoctorId      PrimaryLocation     State     PrimaryLocationState
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
      1              Y                  FL              FL
      1              N                  GA              FL
      2              Y                  TX              TX
      2              N                  CA              TX
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a correlated subquery, or OUTER APPLY to get the Primary Location

```
select  *
from    @t t1
outer apply (
    select  state as PrimaryLocationState
    from    @t t2
    where   t1.doctorid = t2.doctorid
    and     primarylocation = 'Y'
) pl
```

Comment: I think the outer apply seems to be working best because it takes into account instances where there are multiple primary location states.  Thanks!

Comment: @jackstraw22 it typically has a better execution plan than windowed functions also, so i tend to use them more often

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,PrimaryLocationState =max(case when primarylocation='Y' then state end) over (partition by doctorid) 
 from @t
```

**Returns**

```
doctorid    primarylocation state   PrimaryLocationState
1           Y               FL      FL
1           N               GA      FL
2           Y               TX      TX
2           N               CA      TX
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `INNER JOIN`

First you need found out the Primary Location for each doctor.

```
SELECT DoctorID, state as PrimaryLocationState
FROM yourTable
WHERE primarylocation = 'Y';
```

Then add that information to each row

```
SELECT t.*, P.PrimaryLocationState
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN ( SELECT DoctorID, state as PrimaryLocationState
             FROM yourTable
             WHERE primarylocation = 'Y') P
   t.DoctorID = p.DoctorID
```